# unsupported sourceStream NAUDIO

Tags: c#, audio, wav, naudio

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   NAudio.dll
>
> Additional information: Unsupported sourceStream format

This is my current issue! I followed a tutorial on basic playing and pausing of a .wav file in Naudio, random .wav songs I found online throw this exception, yet the .wav that was provided in the video does not.

I can't seem to find an answer to this issue, but I am assuming it has something to do with bitrate of the different .wav files.

Can anyone confirm or deny this?

Comment: to help you troubleshoot this, we need to know what method in NAudio throws this exception, and if possible the WaveFormat of the WAV file you passed in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too ran into this problem, and although am a complete coding beginner I found a solution that works. 
I believe you are referring to giawa videos tutorial - 'C# Audio Tutorial 1 - Wave File with NAudio'

The problem arises when there is different compression methods used for the .wav file: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/89879 
Not sure on the details, but i believe the tutorial uses PCM (stores absolute scale -1.0 - +1.0) where as I (we) used a wave file using ADPCM (stores the differences between samples).

I found the solution here: https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/wiki/Playing-an-Audio-File . 
Basically the class wavefilereader cant actually read my (our) wave files. However another class MediaFoundationReader can (as well any media foundation codec installed on your computer.

Like I said, have no idea what i'm talking about, but it worked for me. Hopefully it helps someone, somewhere.